# Using moment.js with typescript and "module": "amd"

Tags: typescript, momentjs, amd

I'm trying to use moment.js from typescript 2.1.5

I installed moment with npm :

`npm install moment --save-dev`

The d.ts file is included with moment.js so no install via @typings is required
but when I compile my project I get the following error :

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.

Here is a simple test I made to repro the issue.

repro.ts file

```
import * as moment from "moment";
const date = moment().format("YYYY");
console.log(date);
```

tsconfig.json file :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd"
    }
}
```

If i compile with :

```
.\node_modules\.bin\tsc
```

I get the error. I notice that the compilation is fine if I target commonjs module ( "module": "commonjs" in tsconfig )

What is the correct way of using moment if I target amd module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.

When omitted, `moduleResolution` defaults to `classic` unless `module` is `commonjs`, that's the reason your modules are not found in `node_modules`.

Also, it looks like this is [going to be fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11147) in some future release of the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot. All my import are fine with the "node" resolution so it's perfectly fine for me.