# Referencing momentJs in TypeScript without NPM

Tags: typescript, requirejs, momentjs

Using RequireJs, TypeScript transipling to AMD modules. Not using NPM. I have 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' set to true.

I have moment.js v2.17.1 in my libs folder copied from the official repo, and have set it up correctly with RequireJS and at runtime it works perfectly, so this is just a TypeScript compile error.

`TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'`

I have moment.d.ts from the official repo in my typings folder.

`import "moment";`

Gives the same error.

`import moment = require("moment");`

gives `TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.`

Any Ideas?

EDIT: tsconfig.json looks like

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Modify the `moment.d.ts` file from

```
export = moment;
```

To

```
declare module 'moment' {
    export default moment;
}
```

**Discussion:**

Looks like the answer lies in tracing the module resolutions, using

`tsc --traceresolution'`

You can see exactly what it gets up to. For example,

`import moment from 'moment'`

Looks for moment in TypeScript files only:

```
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/moment.ts' does not exist.
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/moment.tsx' does not exist.
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/moment.d.ts' does not exist.
```

Then looks for node packages:

```
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/node_modules/@types/moment.d.ts' does not exist.
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/node_modules/@types/moment/package.json' does not   exist.
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/node_modules/@types/moment/index.d.ts' does not exist.
```

As I am using the straight .js file, I need to use the AMD syntax so it looks for something other than just TypeScript files, eg

`import moment = require('libs/moment')`

Which yields

```
File 'C:/Code/Trunk/Mobile/Project/scripts/libs/moment.js' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
```

Success! Almost! Funnily TSC now gives no errors relating to moment, but at runtime I get this error from RequireJS:

`Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: libs/moment`

Which I can only assume is because `moment.js` doesn't have an AMD export in it, and in my RequireJS config I have:

```
shim: {
    moment: {
        exports: "moment"
    }
}
```

Which creates the AMD export for me. So, the issue is that the JS side of things is fine because RequireJS creates it's own export, but the TS side of things doesn't know that so the compiler complains when I try to use it in TS code.

Even specifying the .d.ts file explicitly doesn't work:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/moment.d.ts" />
```

Gives

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'.
```

So the issue there is that moment doesn't export itself in the way we consume it, eg a namespace, so the only way I got it to work was to modify the `moment.d.ts` file from

```
export = moment;
```

To

```
declare module 'moment' {
    export default moment;
}
```

And it now works perfectly, no imports or anything!

Comment: Thank you! This was the exact solution I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. Try:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives `TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.`

Comment: how about:

import * as moment from "moment";

Comment: hmm, this may be related to you too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41694525/using-moment-js-with-typescript-and-module-amd?rq=1

Comment: That uses NPM, hence using the resolution type `node` helps to get it from the `node_modules` folder, i'm not using node, just grabbing the compiled moment.js file directly.

Comment: The first error, "Cannot find name 'moment'" means that the require line had passed and the moment script itself was found and loaded, but the "moment" definition itself wasn't imported properly. The line I mentioned "import moment from 'moment'" solved that problem for me in my situation (I was using SystemJS instead of AMD requreJS, but I think that's besides the point, they both load as classic and not node).

Comment: I do not know why it could not find the module moment, assuming it found the script, so it could be that moment is not being exported properly. Hence why I thought maybe "import * as moment" may work. But maybe your moment source is not defining properly for AMD, or some other thing. You can try to make your own basic library with export of an AMD module called "moment" and see what happens.